# recognize users with PHPSESSID and cookies

Tags: php, cookies

As far as I know webapps use `session_start();` that implicitly create the session cookie **PHPSESSID** to recognize his users,

but when analysing the outgoing HTTP requests toward differents web applications (yahoo, facebook, gmail, youtube) I didn't see this cookie in the HTTP header but another ones :

*sid, ssid, gmail_at, apisid, sapisid*   in gmail

*datr, lu, c_user, xs, fr*   in facebook...

is one of these cookies is the same as PHPSESSID/JSESSID and they rename it ? (I don't think so, they don't have the same length)

is there another way that `session_start()` and URL Rewriting to distinguish sessions ?

or they create manually the session IDs with `setcookie();` ? what is the advantage then ?

Comment: why do you think that yahoo/gmail/youtube use php?

Comment: because more than 82% of websites use php
reference : https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all
furthermore, I analysed other sites and I never saw the PHPSESSID

Comment: These sites represent the latter 18%. Also there are millions of other sites with phpsessid cookie, almost any forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the session cookie and alter the hash algo

Try [session_name($newName)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to change PHPSESSID.

Or change the cookie value itself with [session_id($string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Also its a server configuration/app behaviour thing. You can safe your cookie to user relation in a file, or in a table.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how about the expiration time ? the sessions in facebook last forever, do you think that they alter also the expiration time of the PHPSESSID or they implement their own way to handle sessions using permanent cookies ?

Comment: In reality within a big software stack like facebook you got a huge stack of different cookies (and other methods) and throwing them all in one pot, merge them and refresh all their times so you wont lost the track.